# Create a product in Magento with different colors (associated products) pointing to the same stock

Tags: magento, magento-1.8, stock, webshop

Is it possible to create a product with different colors where each different color points to the same stock?

For example, I have created a configurable product with a color attribute. After creating the configurable product I create a couple of associated simple products for a few different colors. Instead of having each color have it’s own product qty / stock, I want all the colors to share the same stock.

So for example the configurable product is a lamp. The associated simple products are lamp green, lamp red etc. I want to tell Magento that the lamp product has 10 in stock. So when someone buys a lamp red, it will tell me there are only 9 lamps left in stock regardless of the color. Is this possible?

The way I have it now is that each associated simple product has it’s own stock, but this is not what I want in my case.

Comment: What about using custom option instead if using configurable products?

Comment: I have considered using custom options, but the problem I run into is that I have a product with 2 different sizes. So size A will be small, medium, large and B will be extra large, xxl, xxxl.

With configurable products I could show this as 2 different sizes, A and B, and keep their stocks seperately. But I want customers to be able to select each size seperately. So instead of choosing either A or B, they choose S, M, L, XL etc.

The problem this way is that each size has it's own stock. But I want S, M and L to point to one stock (stock A) and XL, XXL and XXXL to point to stock B.

Comment: hello, this functionality also there in magento.

Comment: @RaviChomal How would you set this up in Magento? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Simple first create configurable product than create it's different simple product with color or size and also remember those product quantity. because on site only simple product are salable not configurable so automatic quantity will be decreasing.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I imagine my comment might be a bit confusing. The way you describe it is the way I currently have it now on my webshop. The problem with this solution is that I can't make 3 different colors/sizes point to the same stock and make them all show on the same product page.

Answer (score 0):

This functionality is not in vanilla magento, so you will need to create/obtain a module that handles it. [this one](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/many-sku-one-inventory.html) seems to do what you need.

If you don't want to pay or prefer to do it yourself, perhaps and easy solution is to keep the stock of your products synchronized.. maybe use observe stock changes or use crons that detect and syncs when they are out of sync.

Comment: I was afraid of that.
Synchronizing the stock of certain products sounds like a possible solution. How would you suggest setting this up for certain associated products of a configurable product?
Thanks for your reply.